# Is the active object and zeroth selected object always the same?

Tags: python, scripting

I see a lot of scripts on BSE that use *for example*

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = context.selected_objects[0]
```

instead of one of

```
cube = context.object
cube = context.active_object
cube = context.view_layer.objects.active # 2.8
cube = context.scene.objects.active # 2.79
```

is the zeroth selected object and the active object always the same

Comment: What's the downvote reason here?

Answer (score 5):

**Not always**

After calling an add primitive operator it is almost always the case that the new object is both active and selected. In which case it rings true.

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object is C.selected_objects[0]
True
```

but the selection can be manipulated such that the active object is None, and there are still selected objects.

```
>>> for o in C.scene.objects:
...     o.select_set(True)
...     
>>> C.view_layer.objects.active = None
>>> C.object is C.selected_objects[0]
False
```

Then not true.

Selecting then setting active object

```
>>> for o in C.scene.objects:
...     o.select_set(True)
...     
>>> C.view_layer.objects.active = None
>>> C.selected_objects[0]
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> C.view_layer.objects.active = C.scene.objects['Cube.001']
>>> C.selected_objects[0]
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

Again not true.

Or no selected objects, with or without an active object

```
>>> C.view_layer.objects.active = C.scene.objects['Cube'] # or None
>>> for o in C.scene.objects:
...     o.select_set(False)
...     

>>> C.object is C.selected_objects[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In conclusion, suggest if you want to be sure it's the active object use `context.active_object` or `context.object`.  *Check if not selected and set selection if need be*  Don't rely on using `context.selected_objects[0]`