# Hiw do I access an imported fbx file with a script after importing it with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Make a LODGroup Empty object ("fbx_type":"LodGroup").
2. Import an asset
3. Parent the asset to the lod group.
4. Duplicate (important: original asset not decimated asset), and decimate asset. Parent it also.
5. Repeat 4 until x many LODS.

Here is my code so far:

```
import bpy
import os.path
from os import path

main_dir="D:\\Documents\\Megascans Library\\Downloaded\\3d\\rock_assembly_siuw3"
model_id=main_dir.split("\\")[-1].split("_")[-1]

bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type="PLAIN_AXES", radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))

lod_group = bpy.context.active_object
lod_group.name="LODGroup"
lod_group["fbx_type"]="LodGroup"

print(main_dir+"\\"+model_id+"_High.fbx")

if os.path.exists(main_dir+"\\"+model_id+"_High.fbx"):
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=main_dir+"\\"+model_id+"_High.fbx")
```

My issue is that bpy.context.active_object doesn't point to the imported fbx after importing and as such I can't parent it to my LODGroup.

Comment: Suggest try: `print (bpy.context.selected_objects[0])`, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/176104/31447 ... btw: How to decimate the asset? Using the decimate modifier or remesh?

Comment: @brockmann Yes `bpy.context.selected_objects[0]` works! I didn't want to know the command for decimating I do know that thankfully.