# How to add a mirror modifier to all objects of a certain collection?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, mirror, collections

I'd like to add a mirror modifier to each object of a certain collection.

The problem is that the modifier will be only added to the last object which even gets the same modifier several times and I don't know why:

```
 def add_empty_collection(self):
    for obj in bpy.data.collections['my_collection'].all_objects:
        print("obj_: ", obj)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # Deselecting all
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_axis[0] = False
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_axis[1] = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].use_axis[2] = False
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Mirror"].mirror_object = bpy.data.objects["target"]
```

**Q:** How to add a mirror modifier to all objects of a certain collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off using `bpy.data.objects` to manipulate them. This way you don't need to rely on what is selected, all you need is the objects name.

```
import bpy

mod_name = 'My-Mirror-Modifier'

for obj in bpy.data.collections["My-Collection"].all_objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        mod = obj.modifiers.new(mod_name, 'MIRROR')
        mod.use_axis[0] = False
        mod.use_axis[1] = True
        mod.use_axis[2] = False
        mod.mirror_object = bpy.data.objects["Light"]
```

Comment: As you have obj from the loop, you don't need to go to bpy.data.objects, use obj directly. Also you'd better get the modifier in a variable mat = obj.modifiers.new(...) and use mat after that (name given as parameter could result in name.001 for instance).

Comment: @lemon is absolutely right (as usual :) thanks lemon) I've updated my answer with his recommendations. (assigning the result of the modifier creation to a variable is new to me, it's good to know!)

Answer (score 2):

**For operators use context.**

*Given the `self` in the question code, making the assumption you are writing an operator*

Further to the answer of [@RoufirHassan](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203486/15543) by way of explanation, looping over the collection objects  de-selecting and selecting single, was not changing the active object.  Adding `context.object` to print statement would confirm this.

[Is the active object and zeroth selected object always the same?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176104/is-the-active-object-and-zeroth-selected-object-always-the-same)

to fix set the active object to the loop object before calling operator.

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
```

[Blender 2.8 API, python, set active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126577/blender-2-8-api-python-set-active-object/126581)

However an issue here would be scripts have a tendency to slow down horribly if looping a lot of operators.  The operator run count using *amended* question code would be  2 x number of objects in collection.

**Modifier add operator adds to the end of modifier stack**

if using the modifiers add operator the newly added modifier will be

```
context.object.modifiers[-1]
```

*ie* the last one.  Once again in blender using name can be dodgy, just like with objects adding another with same name will not have the same name.

**Prime candidate for KeyError**

Never use `bpy.data.whatevers["Foo"]` unless you are certain "Foo" exists. Where it can have value `None`  Also recommend using scene objects, as if the object in `bpy.data.objects` is not linked to scene it likely wont work as expected.

```
target = context.scene.objects.get("Foo")
```

or use the context.  In this case for example, the collection can be context collection (last selected in outliner) and the modifier target can be `context.object`

***Overriding context***

Can pass a context dictionary to operators.  Below is method explained by [@RoufirHassan](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203486/15543) using override.  *Note: this will add all modifiers of first mesh object in collection (including newly added mirror) to all other mesh objects in collection, except to the mirror target if it is a mesh object in same collection*

This will run only 2 operators no matter how many objects are in the collection.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

coll = context.collection
ob = context.object

mesh_obs = [o for o in coll.all_objects 
        if o.type == 'MESH'
        and o is not ob]


if mesh_obs:
    ao = mesh_obs.pop(0)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(
            {"object" : ao},
            type='MIRROR'
            )
    mod = ao.modifiers[-1]
    mod.use_axis = (True, False, True)
    mod.mirror_object = ob
    bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(
            {"object" : ao,
             "selected_editable_objects": mesh_obs
             },
             type='MODIFIERS',
             )
```

**API methods.**

Finally would recommend using the API method as suggested in answer of [@Pysonic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60765/psyonic), except use the context to set collection and modifier target.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the meshes in your collection and add a mirror modifier.

But as you said it will only mirror the active object ( active object = last object selected with different colored outline). So in order to mirror every single object just type (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) *> modifiers*. It will link all objects with the same modifier.

You can use it for any other modifiers.